# Removing multiple items from ConcurrentDictionary based on conditional key

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

Let's say that I have a `ConcurrentDictionary`:

```
var dict = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, someObject>();
dict.TryAdd("0_someA_someB_someC", obj0);
dict.TryAdd("1_someA_someB_someC", obj1);
dict.TryAdd("2_someA_someB_someC", obj2);
dict.TryAdd("3_someA_someB_someC", obj3);
```

The `<number>_` in the keys is incremented and being a dictionary, there is no guarantee that the elements are in order.

Now, imagine I wanted to remove all items from the dictionary that have the `number` less than `2`. I have no idea what the keys will look like, only that they will be prefixed with a number as above.

How can I remove all elements from the dictionary who's key starts with a value less than `2`?

For example, the resulting dict after this process will look like this:

```
dict.TryAdd("2_someA_someB_someC", obj2);
dict.TryAdd("3_someA_someB_someC", obj3);
```

Comment: You can't do this *atomically* without a lock. That might be an issue if you're using a `ConcurrentDictionary` (but not necessarily, depending on why you're using `ConcurrentDictionary` and why you're removing keys). `ImmutableSortedDictionary` is a thing, but may or may not be a good match for your scenario -- again, depending on use.

Comment: For efficiency's sake, instead of indexing on a string, consider a custom key type (or a simple tuple) where these "fields" are split out into actual fields, or else multiple dictionaries (in turn, you could group these in their own custom collection). A concatenated string is a quick and easy way of producing a unique key, but not a good idea if you commonly have to parse the keys. Even if you can't modify callers, keeping a redundant extra collection where you map these keys for quick lookup can be worth it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that is a very interesting idea. I never considered that a possibility. Any chance you can provide a link to an example.

Comment: The `ValueTuple` is easy enough in recent versions of C#: `var d = new ConcurrentDictionary<(int theNumber, string compoundKey), someObject>(); d.TryAdd((2, "2_someA_someB_someC"), obj0); d.Keys.Where(k => k.theNumber < 2)`. `ValueTuple` has suitable implementations of `GetHashCode` and `Equals` to work as a dictionary key. This only optimizes the string parsing and not the fact that we still have to go through all the keys, but that may be enough. The custom adapter that splits dictionaries is a bunch more work that I don't feel like working on. :-P

Comment: @JeroenMostert Great, thanks. I'll have a play with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming it has always this format, you can use LINQ:

```
var keysToRemove = dict.Keys.Where(key => int.Parse(key.Remove(key.IndexOf('_'))) < 2).ToList();
keysToRemove.ForEach(key => dict.TryRemove(key, out someObject obj));
```

`String.Remove` removes the part starting from `_` and then parses the remaiming first part, the number. It will only select the keys which number is lower than 2.
This list will be used to remove the items from the dictionary. Of course you need a lock to make this thread-safe.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with your answer. It appears to answer my question perfectly. I did notice that as soon as you posted it (immediately), someone down voted yours and upvoted Selman Genç's answer. Not saying the two events are related, just pointing out that I noticed it. 

Regarding thread-safety, I was under the impression that the point of the `Concurrent` collections was to allow devs to focus on programming rather than concurrency issues. Are you saying that even with Concurrent collections, we need to use locks and semaphores?

Comment: @pookie: the concurrent collections offer *individual operations* that are efficiently concurrent without further locking. As soon as you want to do more than one thing in an all-or-nothing way, there's still no such thing as a free lunch. Consider the case where this code fetches all the keys, then another thread inserts more keys that also match the check. Those keys will not be gone by the time this loop finishes. Likewise, if another thread removes and then inserts a matching key with a new value, this code can remove that value, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @pookie: there's a lot going on in these two lines. The `Keys`-collection that i'm using is basically a snapshots  of the `ConcurrentDictionary` at the time i have asked for it. Then i'm enumerating all keys and afterwards remove matching items which could take some time. In this time it's possible that the `ConcurrentDictionary` receives more items from another thread that would match the criteria. So while i'm going to delete them, the state of the dictionary has already changed. If you want to prevent that you need a `lock`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert and TimSchmelter Thanks, that makes sense. I thought it was too good to be true...

Comment: Tempted to downvote because of the suggestion to use locks for thread-safety. Combining a `ConcurrentDictionary` with locks makes no sense. If you need to lock, use a `Dictionary` instead. Because when locking you can't be selective. You must lock on **every** access to the collection (both write **and** read). Locking partially is as good as not locking at all. And locking completely a `ConcurrentDictionary` means using two synchronization mechanisms, one on top of the other, with the one being redundant and adding only overhead.

Comment: Continuing on the previous comment - and the answer - you do not need a lock to make this "thread safe" because even if you made it "thread safe" it would not in fact give any new meaningful guarantees. You need to zoom out further and ask yourself what you think you are actually accomplishing and why? Lets pretend we make this "thread-safe" with a lock - great: now as long as we hold that lock (and have locked all other modification with the same lock) we can guarantee that all undesired items are removed.... but really why? As soon as we release the lock the guarantee is gone. Think about...

Comment: ...why you think you need the lock more deeply. It doesn't give many meaningful guarantees to _other_ threads, so the only sure-fire effect is that the current thread very briefly guarantees this local view of a dictionary without some kind of element. Think about the fact that this view, or state of memory, takes a small amount of time to sync to all other threads, and that it dissipates as soon as we release the lock. Should we hold the lock for longer to force this state to be true for longer - or did we only really need it to be true locally for our thread? If so just snap-shot locally.

Comment: ...The only thing accomplished in practice would be that other threads that are trying to modify the collection will briefly pause (lock busy) before then doing whatever modification they needed. Let's say you wanted to count how many of X exists in the dictionary. Well even if you add an extra lock and then count - the result would be inaccurate 0.00001 seconds later. All you accomplished was to FORCE the count to be accurate for a SLIGHTLY extended window of time by blocking other modifications during your lock time-window. A snap-shot would do the same at lower cost and shorter time-window.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse the number that comes before the first underscore (Tip: [`IndexOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2))
2. Convert it to integer (Tip: `int.TryParse`)
3. Compare number to the value (2 in this case)
4. Filter the keys applying this method, store them in a collection. Iterate over the collection and call [`TryRemove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.tryremove?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to remove entries associated with the key.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to iterate across the dictionary collecting the keys that match the criteria and then iterate across that list of keys deleting from the dictionary. A for-each across a dictionary returns items with Key and Value properties, so you can examine the Key property to decide whether or not to delete. You cannot delete in the same loop as this will result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Split` to split the key into an array on the `_` character, convert the first item in the resulting array into an `int` (note this will throw if the key doesn't start with an int), and if it's less than `2`, remove it from the dictionary:

```
foreach (var item in dict.Where(kvp => int.Parse(kvp.Key.Split('_')[0]) < 2))
{
    SomeObject tempObject;
    dict.TryRemove(item.Key, out tempObject);
}
```